# streaming audio from specific xsession to specific client

Tags: pulseaudio, vnc, remote-x-session

I've a good question for you, smart guys:

I need to configure Pulseaudio in order to stream audio from a xsession to a specific client and not to all configured clients.

Here's the situation:
I've got a server which normally has 3 opened sessions on 3 different displays (:1 :2 :3) with the same user. then 3 client connected through VNC. Let's assume that on client 1 through port 5901 I launch VLC on display :1 while on client 2 I launch amarok on display :2. On client 3 another application for example a youtube page on firefox.
My question is:
is there a way to stream audio of display :1 to client 1, display :2 to client 2 and so on?
My server is also a dhcp server with both eth0 and wlan0 (hostapd) configured to receive direct connections from client.

Comment: No solution but 2 remarks that may be important: 1) Pulseaudio runs in a per user session, not per XServer(s). 2) Audio streaming through Pulseaudio is **uncompressed**, i.e. it will eat up **a lot** of bandwith, so it would be much better to serve compressed audio/video files rather than streams.

Comment: @Takkat thank you very much. I imagined that pulseaudio isn't for me googling a bit. What do you suggest to do in order to reach my goal bytheway?